# How to customize input param in R plumber api

Tags: r, api, rest, plumber

I have a API where I want customize input param as per user input(z)

```
#* @param a Enter your Website
#* @param z Enter No of competitor you want to check
#* @param b Enter First URL
#* @param c Enter Second URL
#* @param d Enter Third URL
#* @param e Enter Fourth URL
#* @param f Enter Fifth URL
#* @param g Enter Sixth URL
#* @param h Enter Seventh URL
#* @param i Enter Eighth URL
#* @param j Enter Ninth URL
#* @param k Enter Tenth URL
#* @param v The focused keyword

function(a,z,v) {}
```

is this a right way? can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plumber 1.0.0, make them an array instead?

```
library(plumber)

#* @param a Enter your Website
#* @param b:[chr] Enter URLs
#* @param v The focused keyword
#* @get /something
function(a,b,v) {
  if (length(b) > 10) {
    stop("this api can handle at most 10 urls")
  }
  length(b)
}

#* @plumber
function(pr) {
  pr_set_api_spec(pr, function(spec) {
    spec$paths$`/something`$get$parameters[[2]]$schema$maxItems = 10
    spec
  })
  pr_set_debug(pr, TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Hi,I checked your code but its not giving any field against param b..I want to add as much as urls as user wants to enter..could you help me??

Comment: this is what this does, you could litterally input a thousand url and b would be a character vector of a thousand urls.

Comment: thanks a lot..one more question..if I can fix that user can input max 10 urls in param b?